# Chromium Apps webview: The SSL certificate error page is not responding

Tags: ssl, webview, google-chrome-app

I've embedded an external page in the webview element in the chrome packaged app. This page visits a site of self-signed certificate. The SSL certificate error displays. However, it doesn't respond. That is, pressing 'Proceed anyway' or 'Back to safety' button or 'Help me understand' link doesn't work. The page looks like an image and stuck at there.

[image: ssl error page in the webview in Chrome Apps doesn't respond]

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add onReceivedSslError method in your webview client

```
@Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        // to by pass SSL error
        handler.proceed();
    }
```